# Save custom response in json file in postman

Tags: postman, onclicklistener, postman-testcase, postman-native-app

In postman, I am getting response from 3rd party API and the response contains unnecessary data.

I want to get few keys from the resposne and save in json file when I click on SAVE RESPONSE button inside postman.

```
 "goods": {
        "193651": {
            "goodID": "193651",
            "name": "Erexper",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "11900",
            "categoryID": "0",
            "categoryName": "Без категории",
            "purchasingPrice": "2500"
        },
        "193653": {
            "goodID": "193653",
            "name": "Immunomin",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "11900",
            "categoryID": "0",
            "categoryName": "Без категории",
            "purchasingPrice": "2500"
        },
     
        "193656": {
            "goodID": "193656",
            "name": "Life Factor",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "11900",
            "categoryID": "0",
            "categoryName": "Без категории",
            "purchasingPrice": "2500"
        }
    }
```

From this response, I just want to get all the keys inside goods e.g.

```
{ 193651, 193653, 193656 }
```

Note: I don't want to print in the console and in visualizer section.

I just want to parse the response when SAVE RESPONSE button is clicked.

Or if it is possible to print modified response in the postman response body section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tests tab you could do this

Parsing the Json and getting only the keys you can use this.
[Reference to the post](https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-fetch-the-keys-of-response-body-in-test-script/7419/2)

```
var json = pm.response.json();
const onlyKeys = Object.keys(json["goods"]);
console.log(onlyKeys);
```

Postman says you need to use a visualizer for modifying the response and displaying it and the save response button is always going to save the response you received not the modified one.

I guess you would need to create your own local server which accepts the modified json and saves it to a file, the postman documentation also gives a similar [example](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/3407886-888860dd-9e3c-4537-a78e-1c3f3db7535c?action=share&creator=9355345).

Then you would end up doing something like this.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    pm.sendRequest({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/write',
        method: 'POST',
        header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
        encoding: 'binary',
        body: {
            mode: 'raw',
            raw: onlyKeys
        }
    }, function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
}, 5000);
```